# CodeIgniter Form Validation. Multiple calls not working

Tags: validation, forms, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter. I have been trying to debug a non-working script.

I have come to the conclusion that when utilizing `$this->form_validation->run();` (the form validation class), after the first named call, e.g `$this->form_validation->run(form_1);`, all following calls return true.

I am developing a multi step form and when `$this->form_validation->run(form_1);` correctly returns true, `$this->form_validation->run(form_2);` incorrectly returns true.

Anyone have any clue as to why? Can multiple calls not be held in a single function within a controller or is there a special approach?
Cheers

Comment: Have you set up sets of rules for 'form_1' and 'form_2'? These are not the names of the form in your html, but groups of validation rules. Check 'Creating Sets of Rules' under this http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#savingtoconfig section of the CI user guide. If you can post your relevant controller code that would help too.

Comment: Purposely make the 1st form_validation call return false, then see if the 2nd call to form_validation is still returning true.

Comment: If i make the first form return false, the second form returns nothing (which i assume is false). I have seen numerous posts on the CI forum showing similar problems - is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the way codeigniter is setup doesn't lend itself to allow you to validate with multiple rules, you can extend the form helper with a function to group rules (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/forums/viewthread/120221) or like I did in my `application/config/form_validation.php` I simply combined multiple groups into its own set of rules and referred to the single rule of combined rules.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config = array(

  "campaign" => array(
    array(
      "field" => "campaign[title]",
      "label" => "campaign title",
      "rules" => "trim|required|max_length[255]|xss_clean"
    )
  ),

  "user" => array(
    array(
      "field" => "user_info[email]",
      "label" => "email",
      "rules" => "trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[user_info.email]|max_length[255]|xss_clean"
    )
  )
);

$config["campaign_user"] = array_merge($config['campaign'], $config['user']);
```

The line of interest is the last one, where the two rules are combined:

`$config["campaign_user"] = array_merge($config['campaign'], $config['user']);`

and in your controller you would just call the single rule:

```
if($this->form_validation->run('campaign_user'))
{
    # validation successful
}
```

Comment: hi I'm Facing the same problem , I wanted to execute multiple  rule groups in a single controller the need arise because there are some validations which has to be done only   if checkbox is checked my question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252144/can-i-use-two-validations-group-in-the-same-controller any suggestion would be gratefull

Comment: thanks it work for me. One Confucian is like that can i put this $congif["campaign_user"] in controller or it must be in the validation config file.

Answer (score 0):

pls check if you have pass argument (form1) and (form2) in your  set_rules() function.....and if it's ok then make yourself 1st form_validation call return FALSE, then see if the 2nd call to form_validation is still returning TRUE.

Comment: If i make the first form return false, the second form returns nothing (which i assume is false). I have seen numerous posts on the CI forum showing similar problems - is this simply not possible?