# Using multiple rule sets in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way to call multiple rule sets (The rule sets are in a config file). Such as:

```
$this->form_validation->run('contact_info', 'billing_info')
```

That way I can update a form including all of those rule sets, or just one of those rule sets. If this isn't possible, what is my alternative besides creating a new "merged" rule set. Would I just have to run the validation twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hey i just did this for the first time yesterday ! 
yeah just call the validation twice, once for each set of rules. its pretty cool actually - because like in this example - you can make a custom error message for contact and for billing.

```
with a model named: tigercats

if ( $this->tigercats->_validateContact() == FALSE ) {

     $this->formerrormessage = 'Not enough fur in contact' ; 
     $this->_showValidationFailed() ; }

elseif ( $this->tigercats->_validateBilling() == FALSE ) {

     $this->formerrormessage = 'Claws missing in billing' ; 
     $this->_showValidationFailed() ;  }

 else { $this->_showHappyTigersGetPaid() ; }
```

and obviously you can just run validation twice in a more compressed way if you dont need custom messages.

Answer (score -1):

["the way codeigniter is setup doesn't lend itself to allow you to validate with multiple rules, you can extend the form helper with a function to group rules"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671120/codeigniter-form-validation-multiple-calls-not-working) I think that should help you out, and [this.](http://www.deepcorelab.com/article/how-validate-multiple-forms-one-page-codeigniter)